# Mockito does not work properly with generic types

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following constants:

```
private static final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> USER_ROLES = ImmutableSet.of((GrantedAuthority)ROLE_ADMIN);
private static final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> CUSTOM_GROUPS = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("SOME_GROUP");
```

In test I have the following mocking condition:

```
when(mapper.mapAuthorities(CUSTOM_GROUPS)).thenReturn(USER_ROLES);
```

Mapper in this case it is class that implements `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` spring interface that require to implement this method:

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities);
```

When I tried to perform this mocking condition I get compilation error:

```
The method thenReturn(Collection<capture#2-of ? extends GrantedAuthority>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Collection<capture#2-of ? extends GrantedAuthority>> is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<capture#3-of ? extends GrantedAuthority>)
```

I can fix it just overrite this condition with this one :

```
when(customGroupsMapper.mapAuthorities(CUSTOM_GROUPS)).thenReturn((Collection)USER_ROLES);
```

But actually I don't like warning message that will be appeared: `Collection is a raw type. References to generic type Collection<E> should be parameterized`.

Could someone explain why it's happening and why mockito couldn't match the same types? Are any alternative ways to fix such issue?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this has nothing to do with Mockito, but with way Java handles generics, i.e. with erasure.

What I recommend is to use a simple factory method :

```
when(mapper.mapAuthorities(GROUP)).thenReturn(authorities(ROLE1, ROLE2));

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> ImmutableSet<T> authorities(GrantedAuthority... authorities) {
    return (ImmutableSet<T>) ImmutableSet.copyOf(authorities);
}
```